# yosys fails at ABC pass (on counter.v demo)

Tags: synthesis, yosys

I hope someone can help me with this...

This is my first encounter with yosys. For the start, I'm trying to run the very same demo as Clifford explained in his presentation. I downloaded the demo at the following location: https://github.com/cliffordwolf/yosys/tree/master/manual/PRESENTATION_Intro

yosys run beaks at the ABC pass with following message:

```
12. Executing ABC pass (technology mapping using ABC).

12.1. Extracting gate netlist of module `\counter' to `<abc-temp-dir>/input.blif'..
Extracted 6 gates and 12 wires to a netlist network with 4 inputs and 2 outputs.

12.1.1. Executing ABC.
Running ABC command: <yosys-exe-dir>/yosys-abc -s -f <abc-temp-dir>/abc.script 2>&1
ABC: ABC command line: "source <abc-temp-dir>/abc.script".
ABC: 
ABC: + read_blif <abc-temp-dir>/input.blif 
ABC: + read_lib -w /home/boris/Documents/Self Learning/yosys_synthesys/mycells.lib 
ABC: usage: read_lib [-SG float] [-M num] [-dnvwh] <file>
ABC:               reads Liberty library from file
ABC:    -S float : the slew parameter used to generate the library [default = 0.00]
ABC:    -G float : the gain parameter used to generate the library [default = 0.00]
ABC:    -M num   : skip gate classes whose size is less than this [default = 0]
ABC:    -d       : toggle dumping the parsed library into file "*_temp.lib" [default = no]
ABC:    -n       : toggle replacing gate/pin names by short strings [default = no]
ABC:    -v       : toggle writing verbose information [default = yes]
ABC:    -v       : toggle writing information about skipped gates [default = yes]
ABC:    -h       : prints the command summary
ABC:    <file>   : the name of a file to read
ABC: ** cmd error: aborting 'source <abc-temp-dir>/abc.script'
ERROR: Can't open ABC output file `/tmp/yosys-abc-KDGya6/output.blif'.
[boris@E7440 yosys_synthesys]$
```

I have had a look at the file location mentioned in the error statement above, there is no output.blif in there:

```
[boris@E7440 yosys_synthesys]$ ll /tmp/yosys-abc-KDGya6/
total 12K
-rw-rw-r--. 1 boris boris 542 Jul  5 11:21 abc.script
-rw-rw-r--. 1 boris boris 526 Jul  5 11:21 input.blif
-rw-rw-r--. 1 boris boris 852 Jul  5 11:21 stdcells.genlib
[boris@E7440 yosys_synthesys]$
```

---

Buy the way, here is some system/tools info that might be relevant for debugging:

```
Linux E7440.DELL 4.4.13-200.fc22.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jun 8 15:59:40 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Yosys 0.6+141 (git sha1 080f95f, gcc 5.3.1 -fPIC -Os)

UC Berkeley, ABC 1.01 (compiled Mar  8 2015 01:00:49)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved...

Solution = 
Changed rundir from:

> /home/boris/Documents/Self Learning/yosys_synthesys/mycells.lib

to:

> /home/boris/Documents/SelfLearning/yosys_synthesys/mycells.lib

Lesson learned =
ABC tool does not accept space characters in the path/file name.